# Function realization in Matlab

Tags: matlab, function

I need to write unit step function in Matlab:
[image]

Here is how I tried to realize it:

```
function y = u(n)
    if n<0
        y=0;
    else y=1;
end
```

I tested it for different values of argument and it returns correct values, but if I define array of numbers n=[-2,-1,0,1,2] and call test=u(n) it returns only value 1. What should I do in order to make it return array, I mean function should be evaluated for every value of n and place result of evaluation in array.
Thanks in advance

Comment: There is a builtin `heaviside` function for this in addition to Michael's answer.

Comment: I know but it returns 1/2 at t=0. I need 1 at t=0

Comment: Then `ceil(heaviside(n))`!

Comment: Thanks! I wrote function to do this but your way is very elegant :)

Answer (score 7):

You can do this in one line of code:

```
n>=0
```

The statement above will produce a logical array with elements equal to unity if the corresponding element of n is strictly greater than zero. If you need a function handle to it, use an anonymous function:

```
u = @(n) n>=0
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I solved it:

```
     function y = u(n)
     matrix_dimensions=size(n);
     length_of_vector=matrix_dimensions(2);
     position=0;
     for index=1:length_of_vector
     position=position+1;
     if n(1,index)<0
     y(position)=0;
     else y(position)=1;
     end
     end
     end
```